# My DevEx Repository Item doesn't work

Tags: c#, checkeditems

I am using DevEx grid and also using repository item (check edit) to do this grid's rows selectable.
When i enter the program, my checks doesn't work properly. You see picture below. When i click the check edit, it doesn't respond me.

[image]

Note: I did my grid editable and readonly false. 
I dont know which property must change to do this check edit working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my solution:

1st: Control repository item checked and unchecked values,

2nd: Control hardcoded editable changings (both column and gridview)

3rd: Add column to your datasource datatable for your checkedit column

i did all these things and it works perfect now. :)